# Webcam recording using html5 along with Wowza Streaming Engine 4.0.1

Tags: javascript, html, wowza

I need to record users webcam with audio and save it on the server(Wowza Streaming Engine 4.0.1). So i followed tutorial setting up webcam recording,but this tutorial is using flash.I am wondering 'how to achieve same functionality in html.'

any tips on how to achieve same functionality using html5 , javascript along with Wowza Streaming Engine 4.0.1 ?

plz help me in this.